# Laravel 5.3: Select leftjion is not working with groupBy

Tags: laravel, count, group-by

I would like to count # of posts next to all category item listing as below:

- Category 1 (25)
- Category 2 (12)
- Category 3 (8)
- Category ... (67)

In Laravel 5.2, I use below code to achieve the above result:

```
$cateCount = Category::leftjoin('posts', 'posts.icategoryid', '=', 'categories.id')
          ->groupBy('categories.id')
          ->get(['categories.id', 'categories.name', DB::raw('count(posts.icategoryid) as mycount')]);
```

However, I upgrade to Laravel 5.3, and it show below errors:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'posts.categories.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `categories`.`id`, `categories`.`name`, count(posts.icategoryid) as mycount from `categories` left join `posts` on `posts`.`icategoryid` = `categories`.`id` group by `categories`.`id`)

Could you show me how to fix this or any better way to achieve above result?

Thanks, Vannak

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error, in my case it had to do with MySQL strict mode that would be enabled in 5.3:

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // Behave like MySQL 5.6
        'strict' => false,

        // Behave like MySQL 5.7
        'strict' => true,
    ]
]
```